# How to share object from fixture to all tests using matlab?

Tags: matlab, unit-testing

I make Fixtures.m for realise initialization object Simulation. It looks like:

```
classdef Fixtures < matlab.unittest.fixtures.Fixture
    properties
        SimFixture
    end

    methods (Static)
        function setup()
            fixture = Fixtures.getFixture();
            fixture.initialize();
        end

        function fixture = getFixture()
            persistent fixtureObj;
            if isempty(fixtureObj)
                fixtureObj = Fixtures();
            end
            fixture = fixtureObj;
        end

        function teardown()
            clear all
        end end
    methods
        function obj = initialize(obj)
            obj.SimFixture = Simulation(...);
            obj = obj.SimFixture;
        end
    end end
```

But i would like make singleton Simulation and use it in all my difference tests.
I try to use Fixtures.m in my tests. It's how example test looks like:

```
classdef (TestTags = {'exampletest'})...
    SimulationTest < matlab.unittest.TestCase 
    methods (Test)
        function testUserLinkStats(testCase)
            testCase.applyFixture(Fixtures);
            stats = Fixture.SimFixture.userLinkStats;
            testCase.verifyNotEmpty(stats);
        end
%some different tests
    end end
```

And i try running it in runTests:

```
clear all
import matlab.unittest.TestRunner
import matlab.unittest.TestSuite
% some code 
Fixtures.setup();
runner.run(suiteTestsRun)
close(proj);
%end
```

I don't understand what's wrong? it doesn't work. Someone kind person help me please!
i already try make fixture inside test only for one test, but it didn't work too:(

Comment: When you say 'it doesn't work', what do you expect to happen and what actually happens - any error messages, for example?

Comment: It is hard to help if we don’t know what the problem is. “It doesn’t work” is not nearly specific enough. It would require us to run your code, see what it does, and then more or less guess at what you expected it to do. Know that most of us answer questions without even a MATLAB instance running (or answer while waiting for our MATLAB to finish running something else), and so cannot run your code to understand your question. Help us help you by making everything obvious and explicit.